# How to make a put request using urllib3

Tags: python, http, aws-lambda, urllib3

I am trying to make a put request in AWS lambda. Requests does not comes by default in the python lambda runtime (I know it can be installed using pip and uploading a zip file but this is not what I want.), and requests from botocore is going to get retired soon, so I the only thing I have left is urllib3.

This is how I would do normally using the requests module:

```
import requests
response_body = {'Status': 'SUCCESS',
    'Reason': 'whatever'}
requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(response_body))
```

How can I do the same using urllib3?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it was pretty similar:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response_body = {'Status': 'SUCCESS',
  'Reason': 'whatever'}
r = http.request('PUT', event['ResponseURL'],body=json.dumps(response_body))
```